# WCF:The remote server returned an unexpected response: (405) Method Not Allowed

Tags: .net, wcf

Why in a world I would get this (after hosting this wcf on my IIS) when in fact other wcfs working ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to make interfaces public.

Comment: I'm glad you found your answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

in my case i solved this by filling in the correct url to the service in the config file

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost/MyServices/MyService.svc"
```

i am using VS2010 .Net3.5

Comment: That's funny... the accepted answer to the [ProtocolException Unhandled/(405) Method not allowed with WCF; Bindings and Endpoints look right though](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004206/protocolexception-unhandled-405-method-not-allowed-with-wcf-bindings-and-endp) says exactly the opposite. They *removed* the URL from the `endpoint address` to fix their problem... that just goes to show what a huge pain working with WCF is!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, run the following command as **administrator** (this is for windows 7/2008):

**C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg -i**

With that, the problem has gone in my experience.

Comment: Wow... not even a description of what that command that you're telling everyone to run does, eh?

Comment: I'm just surprised that you telling users to run a command on their computer without even providing any details of what they'll be running. I'm sure that *we* know what it is and what it does, but developers that are new to WCF (the ones that will be looking for posts like this one) probably won't know. I'm just pointing out that your answer *could* be more informative and more helpful to these users... a link to some details and a short description of what the command should do would be a good start.

Comment: I just ran this command and now my application does not work at all ... It gives the following error: **Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.**