# ProtocolException Unhandled/(405) Method not allowed with WCF; Bindings and Endpoints look right though

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I'm just learning how to use WCF and I am trying to write a little HelloWorld program from scratch (both the host and client sides).  I've been getting a `ProtocolException Unhandled` whenever my client tries to use the service, and I can't figure out why.  I'm hosting the service using IIS.

Regarding the way I have things set up: I'm doing my best to separate the client, proxy, host, service, and contract as detailed in this [video](http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=122) and as outlined in this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114139/WCF-The-Right-Way-A-Quick-Reference-Guide).  Basically I've got different projects within the solution for each of those.

Here are some different files showing what I'm talking about:

### Service

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
  public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
  {
    public String GetMessage(String name)
    {
        return "Hello World from " + name + "!";
    }
  }
}
```

### Contract

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IHelloWorldService
  {
      [OperationContract]
      String GetMessage(String name);
  }
}
```

### Proxy

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
  public class Proxy : ClientBase<IHelloWorldService>, IHelloWorldService
  {
    #region IHelloWorldService Members

    public String GetMessage(String name)
    {
        return Channel.GetMessage(name);
    }

    #endregion

  }
```

}

### Client

```
namespace Client
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
        MessageBox.Show(proxy.GetMessage(textBox1.Text));
    }
  }
```

}

The client is just a form with a textbox and a button, and it tries to execute GetMessage() using whatever is in the textbox as a parameter.  There is another class that actually creates an instance of the form.

Here's my web.config for the website:

### Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior> 
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloWorld.HelloWorldService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8002/" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloWorld.IHelloWorldService"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And here's my app.config that goes with the client:

### app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:8002/" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloWorld.IHelloWorldService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

My svc file is very short, just:

### HelloWorldService.svc

```
<%@ServiceHost Service="HelloWorld.HelloWorldService"%>
```

I know the service is running, because when I navigate to `http://localhost:8002/HelloWorldService.svc` in my browser I get the screen that says

> You have created a service.
>
> To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to
>   call the service.

So here's where the snag happens: the service is running using IIS, I start an instance of the client, the window with the textbox and the button come up, I type in some letters, hit the button, and then the program crashes and I get the `ProtocolException Unhandled, (405) Method not allowed.`  The error happens on this line of the Proxy class:

```
return Channel.GetMessage(name);
```

I've been trying to figure this out for hours and hours, and I haven't made much progress.  If someone could at least point me in the right direction, I would be very appreciative.

Last thing: I want to write the client and proxy from scratch, without using svcutil.exe.

Comment: An update: I ran this command:

"%WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\ServiceModelReg.exe" -r


and the error changed.  It's on the same line, but now it says:

The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

Comment: Also, when I use the resolution for this new error detailed [at this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169179(v=nav.70).aspx), it switches back to the previous error I was getting; 405 Method Not Allowed.  When I run the command in my previous comment, it switches back again to the "content type does not match" error.  Maybe this will provide someone with an additional clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found a solution, although I'm not entirely sure why it works.  I guess when you are using Cassini or IIS or whatever to host the website, you're not supposed to specify an address in the endpoint in the web.config file.  All I had to do was change it to `address=""` and it started working properly.  Be sure to make sure the port your server is hosting the service on matches the code in your app.config file.

Answer (score 102):

The reason it works when you go to the base address (.svc) is that this is an HTTP GET operation to get the metadata for the service.  When you call a method on your service contract, you're doing a POST operation and more than likely you just don't have this feature enabled.  Depending on the .NET version you're targeting, it will be one of these highlighted in red.

[image]

Comment: When I navigate to Windows Features, the option for .NET Framework 3.5 and it's subfolders are already checked.

There is not folder for .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services.  This is strange, because it is installed on the computer (if I navigate to the menu where I can uninstall programs, I see Microsoft .NET Framework, Microsoft .NET Framework Multi-Targeting Pack, and Microsoft .NET Framework SDK).  Any idea why those options might not be showing up?

Comment: thank you.  Maybe i just don't understand Windows or IIS well enough, but these windows features settings just seem so random, buried and unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

You have to specify full address for your service in the endpoint tag of Client configuration.
Like this:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:8002/HelloWorldService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloWorld.IHelloWorldService" />
```

Do not forget to add **'.svc'** extension after your service name in address attribute of endpoint tag. It worked for me. Hope you will get the solution now.

Client config will look like this:

```
 <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IService"/>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost:61569/Service1.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService" contract="WcfServiceApp.IService1" name="WSHttpBinding_IService"/>
</client>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify full address for your service in the endpoint tag of Client configuration

address="http://localhost:8002/HelloWorldService.svc", where you put same endpoint configurations.

It did work for me while I trapped in hell...

Answer (score 1):

Enabling below two components, worked for me.

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: FYI: it looks to me that the most voted answer is a more specific, targeted version of this answer.  (pointing out the specific items under each framework to include)