# WCF Client with ChannelFactory, method returns ProtocolException / 405 Method not Allowed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am writing a part of the program, which is used for communication between client and server.

Service only forwards the query to the database. But when I try to send a query I get an exception "ProtocolException / (405) Method not allowed".

I tried answers from [ProtocolException Unhandled/(405) Method not allowed with WCF; Bindings and Endpoints look right though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004206/protocolexception-unhandled-405-method-not-allowed-with-wcf-bindings-and-endp), but nothing helped.

Here are some of my files:

**Client for communication** It is library, because we want to use it from Unity and I also want this code in tests.

```
namespace Client
{
    public class ClientCommunicationWcf : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly ChannelFactory<ITask> _taskFactory;


        public ClientCommunicationWcf()
        {
            _taskFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITask>("localhost");
        }

        public T GetResponse<T>(string commandName, object data)
        {
            var channel = _taskFactory.CreateChannel();
            channel.Execute(commandName, data);
            return (T)channel.ResponseObject;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _taskFactory.Close();
            ((IDisposable) _taskFactory).Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

**DataContract**

```
namespace CommunicationCommonLib.Requests
{
    [DataContract]
    [KnownType(typeof(LoginUserRequest))]
    public class LoginUserRequest
    {
        [DataMember]
        private readonly string _username;
        [DataMember]
        private readonly string _password;


        public LoginUserRequest(string username, string password)
        {
            _username = username;
            _password = password;
        }


        public string Username
        {
            get { return _username; }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
        }
    }
}
```

**ServiceContract**

```
namespace CommunicationCommonLib
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITask
    {
        object ResponseObject
        {
            [OperationContract]
            get;
        }

        /// <param name="data"></param>
        [OperationContract]
        void Execute(string commandName, object data);
    }
}
```

**Service**: 
IServerTask is child of ITask

```
namespace WcfService2
{
    public class ServerTaskService : IServerTask, ITask
    {
        private object _responseObject;


        public object ResponseObject
        {
            get { return _responseObject; }
        }


        public void Execute(string commandName, object data)
        {
            DataCommands.RunCommand(commandName, data, this);
        }

        public void SetResponse(object response)
        {
            _responseObject = response;
        }
    }
}
```

**Web.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService2.ServerTaskServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.ServerTaskServiceBehavior" name="WcfService2.ServerTaskService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding" contract="CommunicationCommonLib.ITask" />
      </service>
    </services>  
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />


    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="01:00:00" sendTimeout="04:00:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="209715200" maxBufferSize="52428800" maxReceivedMessageSize="52428800"
          textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Streamed" useDefaultWebProxy="false"
          messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="52428800" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

**App.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:55555/Task" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="CommunicationCommonLib.ITask" name="localhost"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Address "http://localhost:5555/Task" is also set in WcfService2 - Properties - Web, where it is used IIS Express.
I wrote WPF application for testing client server communication, where is stored App.config. WPF is only for sending request and checking the result.

Web.config may be wrong, because it is my first WCF and I tried different things from examples.

When I run program, browser open "http://localhost:5555/Task", so I think that service is running.

Thanks for help.

**EDIT:** ServerTaskService is child of IServerTask and ITask.

Comment: When you're debugging your service, do client calls reach the `Execute`-method? To preclude any issues with the database-part you could add a simply dummy-method just to ensure, simple invocations of your service work.

Comment: I tried it and client don't reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your service contract name is ITask while your service class implements some different interface i.e. IServerTask. Please correct service class definition.

Comment: I set all to ITask and I get the same exception.