# wcf service message based activation getting a strange error

Tags: wcf

I developed a basic wcf service using just a .svc file, and a library
If I call the service via debug it shows me a page with some links , between which I find  my .svc file : when I click on it I get the following error message :

*Name cannot begin with the '%' character, hexadecimal value 0x25. Line 1, position 2.*

The .svc file contains the following :

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#"  Debug="true" Service="WcfServiceMessageBasedActivationLibrary1.Service1" %>
```

where WcfServiceMessageBasedActivationLibrary1.Service1 is the library containing the real implementation.

If I create an application on IIS pointing to the same folders , I get the same error.
The error message is nonsense to me, since there is no "name" starting with "%" in any part of the source code.
I tried every option that was humanly possible , without any effect.
What is the cause of the problem ?

Comment: Right click on your virtual directory and select the .NET tab, check your IIS Manager and make sure the .NET version dropdown is correct.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004206/protocolexception-unhandled-405-method-not-allowed-with-wcf-bindings-and-endp

Comment: Its not a virtual directory but the default web site : if I right click it I don't get any ,net tab.

Comment: on the other side, if I put it under a virtual directory inside the default web site, i still don't get any .net tab.

Comment: To verify that HTTP activation is enabled, go to Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off -> Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5
There should be a checkbox to enable Windows Communication Foundation HTTP. This should be checked. You can check the link provided in my last comment.

Comment: I checked where you told , Programs and Features > Turn Windows Features on or off > Microsoft.net FRamework 3.5 : here I don't have any WCF reference, but I got it in the corresponding .Net Framework 4.8 advanced Services , which has both Http Activation and TCP Port sharing enabled

Comment: apparently , in my  web.config file there was a section <system.webServer> which  was creating the problem. I have no idea if this section has always been present, I had never seen it before, but truth is that, by removing it, I can correctly reach the service at least via browser. Its like I was configuring the app for a self hosting and at the same time trying to host it under IIS, which probably created some confusion.

Comment: But if I put the service into a web application the problem starts again. It seems there's really no solution to this mistery .